# Return decimal value in SQL query

Tags: sql, database, decimal

Example of script

```
,sum(BREAKS)/3600 as Breaks
```

but it comes back as a whole number, how can I get decimals?

Comment: By casting it to one. An expression only contained `int`s will return an `int`.

Comment: Also, don't tag conflicting RDBMS; only tag the one you are *actually* using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options.  First, you could force an implicit cast by introducing a decimal into the calculation:

```sql
SUM(BREAKS) / 3600.0 AS Breaks
```

An alternative would be to use an explicit cast to decimal:

```sql
CAST(SUM(BREAKS) / 3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Breaks
```

Comment: The suspense is killing me.

Comment: @Strawberry Not so loud!  Gordon might hear us talking and come here to answer.

Comment: The first method is much the simpler.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen .. Im still learning but I didnt even think it would be so simple. I appreciate you